# Fill in the gaps between values in table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, lag, window-functions, lead

I have a table (MySQL)

```
UserID | CreationTS | Type         | Value    | Bonus Value    
259275 | 2012-08-01 | Deposit      | -------- | NULL
259275 | 2012-08-02 | BonusApplied |      175 | 175
259275 | 2012-08-03 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 175
259275 | 2012-08-06 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 175
259275 | 2012-08-10 | BonusApplied |      180 | 180
259275 | 2012-08-11 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259275 | 2012-08-12 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259275 | 2012-08-15 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259275 | 2012-08-17 | BonusApplied |      200 | 200
259275 | 2012-08-18 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 200
259681 | 2012-08-01 | Deposit      | -------- | NULL
259681 | 2012-08-02 | BonusApplied |      175 | 175
259681 | 2012-08-03 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 175
259681 | 2012-08-06 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 175
259681 | 2012-08-10 | BonusApplied |      180 | 180
259681 | 2012-08-11 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259681 | 2012-08-12 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259681 | 2012-08-15 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 180
259681 | 2012-08-17 | BonusApplied |      200 | 200
259681 | 2012-08-18 | TradeOrder   | -------- | 200
```

I need to fill in the gaps in the VALUE filled, between BonusApplied type, per UserID, based on the first Value per user and BonusApplied. 
The final value is in the Bonus Value column. That's what I need.
If there is a solution based on @variables instead of the JOIN, it would be great.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE bonusTable (userID INT UNSIGNED, CreationTs DATE, `Type` CHAR(32), `Value` INT UNSIGNED, BonusValue INT);

INSERT INTO bonusTable VALUES
(259275, '2012-08-01', 'Deposit', NULL, NULL),
(259275, '2012-08-02', 'BonusApplied', 175, 175),
(259275, '2012-08-03', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 175),
(259275, '2012-08-06', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 175),
(259275, '2012-08-10', 'BonusApplied', 180, 180),
(259275, '2012-08-11', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259275, '2012-08-12', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259275, '2012-08-15', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259275, '2012-08-17', 'BonusApplied', 200, 200),
(259275, '2012-08-18', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 200),
(259681, '2012-08-01', 'Deposit', NULL, NULL),
(259681, '2012-08-02', 'BonusApplied', 175, 175),
(259681, '2012-08-03', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 175),
(259681, '2012-08-06', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 175),
(259681, '2012-08-10', 'BonusApplied', 180, 180),
(259681, '2012-08-11', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259681, '2012-08-12', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259681, '2012-08-15', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 180),
(259681, '2012-08-17', 'BonusApplied', 200, 200),
(259681, '2012-08-18', 'TradeOrder', NULL, 200);


SET @VUserID := NULL;
SET @VValue := NULL;

SELECT CreationTs, `Type`, IF(@VUserID = userID, IF(`Value` IS NULL, @VValue, @VValue := `Value`), @VValue := `Value`) BonusValue, @VUserID := userID userID FROM bonusTable ORDER BY userID, CreationTs;

#Cols in original order:
SELECT userID, CreationTs, `Type`, BonusValue FROM (
SELECT CreationTs, `Type`, IF(@VUserID = userID, IF(`Value` IS NULL, @VValue, @VValue := `Value`), @VValue := `Value`) BonusValue, @VUserID := userID userID FROM bonusTable ORDER BY userID, CreationTs
) A;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please consider accepting the answer (green tick) in the case it was the most helpful given and answered your question, or upvoting if it was useful. This way my value to the community is reflected and when I get stuck and ask a question the probability of a useful answer increases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JOIN type solution:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,seq INT NOT NULL
,value INT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,seq)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(101, 1,NULL),
(101, 2,175),
(101, 4,NULL),
(101, 7,NULL),
(101, 9,180),
(101,11,NULL),
(102, 2,NULL),
(102, 3,175),
(102, 4,NULL),
(102, 7,NULL),
(102, 9,200),
(102,12,NULL);

SELECT x.*
     , MAX(y.value) i 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.seq <= x.seq 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id,x.seq;
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| id  | seq | value | i    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 101 |   1 |  NULL | NULL |
| 101 |   2 |   175 |  175 |
| 101 |   4 |  NULL |  175 |
| 101 |   7 |  NULL |  175 |
| 101 |   9 |   180 |  180 |
| 101 |  11 |  NULL |  180 |
| 102 |   2 |  NULL | NULL |
| 102 |   3 |   175 |  175 |
| 102 |   4 |  NULL |  175 |
| 102 |   7 |  NULL |  175 |
| 102 |   9 |   200 |  200 |
| 102 |  12 |  NULL |  200 |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

Comment: @Martin that's a big question.  A useful trick is to consider what rows would be returned if we removed the aggregating functions and replaced the GROUP BY clause with an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I was really just enquiring as to some form of explanation as to why the SQL you posted works, thanks `:-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: @levihaskell but 3 years on, who cares?

Comment: @Strawberry I have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer by [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43525840/1566634) but works for both, ascending and descending bonus values:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,seq INT NOT NULL
,value INT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,seq)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(101, 1,NULL),
(101, 2,175),
(101, 4,NULL),
(101, 7,NULL),
(101, 9,180),
(101,11,NULL),
(102, 2,NULL),
(102, 3,175),
(102, 4,NULL),
(102, 7,NULL),
(102, 9,150),
(102,12,NULL);

SELECT
    x.*,
    (SELECT value FROM my_table
        WHERE id = x.id
        AND seq = MAX(y.seq)) filled
FROM my_table x
LEFT JOIN my_table y
    ON y.id = x.id
    AND y.seq <= x.seq
    AND y.value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    x.id, x.seq
```

The result:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| id  | seq | value | i    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 101 |   1 |  NULL | NULL |
| 101 |   2 |   175 |  175 |
| 101 |   4 |  NULL |  175 |
| 101 |   7 |  NULL |  175 |
| 101 |   9 |   180 |  180 |
| 101 |  11 |  NULL |  180 |
| 102 |   2 |  NULL | NULL |
| 102 |   3 |   175 |  175 |
| 102 |   4 |  NULL |  175 |
| 102 |   7 |  NULL |  175 |
| 102 |   9 |   150 |  150 |
| 102 |  12 |  NULL |  150 |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

How it works:

1. The self join adds all *non-empty* preceding rows with the same id to each original row via `y.seq <= x.seq` and `y.value IS NOT NULL` expressions
2. The `GROUP BY x.id, x.seq` clause allows us to select the highest preceding seq number via `MAX(y.seq)`
3. The select list sub-query looks up the value of the most immediate non-empty preceding row within the same id group